# Запретить редактирование первых n символов в input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Есть input type text с заданным значением:

```
<input type='text' name='url' id='url' value='www.site.ru/' />
```

Нужно, что бы пользователь не мог стереть www.site.ru/ а только дополнить его таким образом выбирая желаемый адресс страницы.

Как это можно сделать? Смотрю плагин с масками ввода, но подобной задачи кажется он не решает..
Есть ли какое то быстрое готовое решение..
Нужно как то запретить редактирование первых 11 символов, даже проверять их значения нет нужды..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вариант ...

```js
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var url = document.querySelector("#url"),
     val = str = url.defaultValue,
     flag;
   url.value = val;
   url.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
     if (url.selectionStart > val.length - 1 && !flag) str = url.value, str = str.slice(val.length), str = val + str;
     flag = false;
     url.value = str
   });
   url.addEventListener("paste", function(event) {
     if (url.selectionStart < val.length) flag = true
   })
 });
```

```html
<input type='text' name='url' id='url' value='www.site.ru/' />
```

Comment: при вводе внутри `www.site.ru/` добавляется лишний `/`

Comment: атрибут `value` не меняется при редактировании? Тогда бы его и использовал в своём решении. Кому хочется лишние буквы набирать, когда под рукой есть всё, что надо.

Comment: Да, увы слеши плодятся если поставить в самое начало строки курсор кнопкой home и далее что то набирать..

Comment: @htclog81 посмотрите дополненный вариант

Comment: @Grundy будут ли какие-то замечания по исправленному варианту

Comment: @рони А теперь представьте такую ситуацию. Пользователь ввел www.site.ru/foo. Всё замечательно, запись сохранилась в базе. На следующий день понимает, что ошибся. Надо написать www.site.ru/bar. Программа генерит `<input value="www.site.ru/foo"/>` и никто уже не может убрать вот этот вот "foo".

Comment: @Sergey какая программа это генерит???

Comment: @рони моя программа генерит, но я знаю что с этим делать. проехали.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала заготовить обработчики событий и функцию установки обработчиков.
Ни какая кросс-браузерность никогда не планировалась. Работает в моём браузере (chrome) и ладно.

```js
    // Устанавливает обработчики, если они ещё не установлены
    // Может кому-то это будет лишним, но мне надо именно так
    function fixedInputInit(input) {
        var eventsArray = ['keydown', 'paste', 'cut', 'input'];
        var events = $._data(input[0], 'events' );
        if (events) {
            for (var i = 0; i < eventsArray.length; i++) {
                var eventHandlers = events[eventsArray[i]];
                if (eventHandlers) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < eventHandlers.length; j++) {
                        if (eventHandlers[j] === fixedInputEventListener) return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        input.on('keydown paste cut input', null, fixedInputEventListener);
    }

    // Обработчик-диспетчер перенаправляет каждый тип в свой обработчик
    // На фига он нужен? Чтобы иметь дело с одним обработчиком, а не тремя
    function fixedInputEventListener(event) {
        if (event.type === 'paste') return fixedInputPasteHandler(event);
        if (event.type === 'cut') return fixedInputCutHandler(event);
        if (event.type === 'keydown') return fixedInputKeydownHandler(event);
        if (event.type === 'input') return fixedInputInputHandler(event);
    }

    // Против новомодных крестиков
    function fixedInputInputHandler(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var fixedLength = parseInt(target.dataset.fixedLength, 10);
        if (target.value === '') target.value = target.defaultValue.substr(0, fixedLength);
    }

    // Это чтобы не пастили в фиксированную часть
    function fixedInputPasteHandler(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var fixedLength = parseInt(target.dataset.fixedLength, 10);
        if (target.selectionStart < fixedLength && target.selectionEnd > -1) event.preventDefault();
    }

    // А это чтобы не вырезали из фиксированной части
    function fixedInputCutHandler(event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var fixedLength = parseInt(target.dataset.fixedLength, 10);
        if (target.selectionStart < fixedLength && target.selectionEnd > -1) event.preventDefault();
    }

    // Ну и чтобы не печатали в фиксированной части
    function fixedInputKeydownHandler(event) {
        var keyCodes = [9, 35, 36, 37, 39]; // tab, home, end, left arrow, right arrow
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if (keyCodes.indexOf(keyCode) !== -1) return; 
        var target = event.target;
        var fixedLength = parseInt(target.dataset.fixedLength, 10);
        if (target.selectionStart < fixedLength && target.selectionEnd > -1) event.preventDefault();
        if (keyCode === 8 && target.selectionStart === fixedLength && target.selectionEnd === fixedLength) event.preventDefault();
    }

// Активируется так:  
$('input').each(function() { fixedInputInit($(this)); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-fixed-length="12" value="www.site.ru/foo" />
```

Как видно на элементе `input` должен быть атрибут `data-fixed-length="Сколько_вам_надо"`:
`<input ... data-fixed-length="12" ... />`

Активируется так:
`$('input').each(function() { fixedInputInit($(this)); });`

Преимущества:
Блокировка прямо на вводе, поэтому нет нужны исправлять строку после каждого нажатия каждой кнопки. Всё сразу вводится правильно, либо отклоняется без лишних телодвижений.
Элемент GUI input является одним целым. При прокрутке (когда текст длинный) фиксированная часть тоже прокручивается (уходит за границу поля), а не закрывает собой "невидимый" участок поля ввода.

Comment: Увы в IE последней версии который в win 10 не работает, стоит нажать на крестик который в правом верхнем углу отображается как сбрасывается все содержимое поле и более ввести не возможно.

Comment: Можно попробовать отслеживать событие `input`, если строка пустая, то записать туда обратно `www.site.ru/`

Comment: Выпустил хотфикс на скорую руку. Хотя с таким раскладом надо кое-что пересмотреть более основательно. В ie 11 работает.

Comment: Да и в моем IE теперь работает!

Answer (score 0):

```js
//  Обработчик удаляет из input указанную в data-remove строку, чтобы небыло повтора
$('#url').on('keyup input cut paste', function(e){
 var input = $(this);
 //  Это для того, чтобы при paste обработка выполнилась уже после
 //  изменения значения в input
 setTimeout(function() {
  var remove = new RegExp('^' + input.attr('data-remove'));
  var val = input.val();
  if (val.match(remove))
  {
   input.val(val.replace(remove, ''));
  }
 }, 0);
});
```

```css
div.input {
  border:#CCC 1px solid;
  display:inline-block;
  height:20px;
  line-height:20px;
  padding:0 4px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
div.input input {
  border:none;
  background:none;
  outline:none;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input">www.site.ru/<input type='text' name='url' id='url' value="" data-remove="www.site.ru/" /></div>
```

Comment: Проверка что бы не ввели в сам input повторно site.ru избыточно в моем задаче, введенное и так проверяем при отправке, на повторность, только латинские символы итд. Хотелось именно что бы site.ru был внутри input а не визуально с помощью стилей казался в input тк таким образом мы уже сделали..